# IOS Core plot how to get the nearest possible value of minimum Y axis value

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph, core-plot

I am using below code to calculate the range of YAxis value:

```
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yLow_NBH)
                                                length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yHigh_NBH - yLow_NBH )];
axisSet.yAxis.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 4.0;
axisSet.yAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyEqualDivisions;
```

I want  graph to start Y axis from best possible nearest value of Y minimum value.For example if Ymin is 5000 and intervals between two values is 500 then yAxis should start from 4500,5000,5500 and so on.

Thanks in advance

I need the graph as second image if the Ymin is 9000

[image]

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "best". With the given values, 5,000 seems like a good number to start the range unless you need to leave extra space at the edges of the range for things like plot symbols or data labels. Are there any other factors like that to consider?

Comment: best possible value means whatever value is for yMin Yaxis should start from nearest YMin value based on the interval difference.Suppose I have three values 5000,6500,9000 so YMin= 5000 and YMax =9000.So range will be 5000,6000,7000,8000,9000.And for 0 index YAxis value will be 5000 which may seem like nothing has plotted(No scattered line will be visible) since 5000 is minimum.I don't want to keep the value of Ymin as "0" because for higher values ,Interval will also be very high. I want the range as 4000,5000,6000 etc so that plotting of 5000 value can be seen in the graph

Comment: Eric I have attached the images in my main post so that you can have an idea what exactly my requirement is.

Comment: Thanks Eric for formatting the code.Please let me know how can I achieve this?

Comment: Eric just want to add one more thing that values of Yaxis are coming dynamically so I can not fix the interval.It is very urgent for me.Really need your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would stick with the default labeling policy, `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval`. You can choose the `majorIntervalLength` when you determine the preferred plot range and be assured the tick locations will fall at the desired values.

Take a look at how Core Plot determines tick locations with the `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic` labeling policy (see [this method](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/blob/master/framework/Source/CPTAxis.m#L953)). You can use the same algorithm to find the best tick interval and then adjust the starting location and length of the range to fall on even multiples of the tick interval. Note that Core Plot does all of the math with decimal values so it stays accurate with very large and very small values. You can use `double` values to simplify the code if you know your data will always fall in a range that won't cause numeric accuracy issues.